# Transparency on pixel level?

Tags: java, rendering, per-pixel

I'm using java and I do pixel-by-pixel rendering (a pixel array from an ARGB BufferedImage). So a color is 0xAARRGGBB. Now how can I render a transparent color? I guess that I should manipulate the existing pixel and not overwrite it. I can make color addition simply:

```
public static int additiveColor(int c1, int c2) {
        int red = (c1 & 0x00ff0000) + (c2 & 0x00ff0000);
        int grn = (c1 & 0x0000ff00) + (c2 & 0x0000ff00);
        int blu = (c1 & 0x000000ff) + (c2 & 0x000000ff);
        return 0xff000000 + (red > 0x00ff0000 ? 0x00ff0000 : red) + (grn > 0x0000ff00 ? 0x0000ff00 : grn) + (blu > 0x000000ff ? 0x000000ff : blu);
    }
```

So to set a pixel to a sum of two colors I just do this:

```
pixels[i] = additiveColor(c1, c2);
```

How can I do transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You want linear interpolation using the alpha channel of the incoming (source) pixel.

This goes by different names in different APIs (`mix (...)` in OpenGL, `lerp (...)` in D3D). No matter what you call it, it boils down to the following:

```
public static int alpha_blend(int c1, int c2) {
    int a1 = (c1 & 0xff000000) >>> 24;
    //int a2 = (c2 & 0xff000000) >>> 24; // Do not need for traditional alpha blending

    int r1 = (c1 & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    int r2 = (c2 & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;

    int g1 = (c1 & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
    int g2 = (c2 & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;

    int b1 = (c1 & 0x000000ff);
    int b2 = (c2 & 0x000000ff);

    float src_alpha = ((float)a1) / 255.0f;

    int red   = (r1 * src_alpha) + (r2 * (1.0f - src_alpha));
    int green = (g1 * src_alpha) + (g2 * (1.0f - src_alpha));
    int blue  = (b1 * src_alpha) + (b2 * (1.0f - src_alpha));

    return (a1 << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue;
}
```

You might need some casts to make Java happy, I would not consider this more than pseudo-code to give you an idea of what needs to happen.

Comment: Hmm... there's something weird about the green and blue. If I render a red rectangle, I get a red one. But if I render a blue rectangle, I get a white one, and if I render a green one, I get a yellow one.

Comment: @LPeter1997: Can I ask how the values of `c1` and `c2` are determined? I am operating under the assumption that `c2` is the color of what's already rendered and `c1` is the color you are trying to blend. If you could show a screenshot of the situation you are describing, that might help.

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t34.0-12/10836287_792331930812888_302713311_n.jpg?oh=41e2fdf755e7327084d4c72d108ee760&oe=5485F814&__gda__=1418072523_d1d77f4cdac8f9c26d5c53212f6fc658

And the rendering: pixels[pos] = ColorUtils.alphaBlend(color, pixels[pos]);

Comment: @LPeter1997: I think the fact that Java doesn't have unsigned data types is causing this. If that is the case, then the operator you need to use when calculating `a1` is actually `>>>` rather than `>>`.

Comment: Thanks, now the colors are correct, except for the white parts around the red dots.

Comment: @LPeter1997: I don't know how to explain that one. I suspect you are using some gradient function to calculate the color and alpha value. I would check for under/overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19243/discussion-between-lpeter1997-and-andon-m-coleman).